# Use Node.js (and NPM package 'psd') to parse Adobe PSD file, programatically replace image layer and then save/render as PNG

Tags: node.js, png, render, psd

For a project I need to to parse an *Adobe Photoshop PSD file*, programatically find and replace an image layer and then save it back to a PSD file and/or export it as PNG (or JPEG). I do not have a lot of experience with Adobe Photoshop but I think these types of layers are called 'smart layers'.

The use case:

Render mockup preview image

- User uploads image to Node HTTP server
- Replace layer in PSD with
  uploaded image (image fill layer)
- Render as PNG/JPEG and write to HTTP response

The replacement layer is 3d skewed over x and y for a mockup template. I have included an image to illustrate what this means. Additional mockup templates will be created in the future which is why I think labeling the replacement layer with a constant value is the way to implement this.

The template file:
[image: template file]

The uploaded image:
[image: uploaded image]

The final rendered image
[image: output image]

I don't need help with the HTTP server/authentication etc, that part is trivial. I am **only** looking for a method to replace the image layer.

The PSD files are/will be custom made for this particular project. To identify the right layer to replace based on the layer name (label) is an acceptable implementation.

I have had a look at several NPM packages to do this job but was not able to get a functioning prototype. This package seems the most promising.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/psd

I currently have the following code:

```
/* mockup.js */
var PSD = require('psd')
var psd = PSD.fromFile("mockup.psd")
var fs = require('fs')

psd.parse()

/* For easier reference */
var replacementLayer, file, fileBuffer

let tree = psd.tree()

let layers = tree.layer.node._children

for(let layer of layers) {
    /* i named the layer 'replacementLayer' */
    if(layer.name == 'replacementLayer') { 
        replacementLayer = layer 
        file = replacementLayer.layer.file
        fileBuffer = replacementLayer.layer.file.data
    }
}

/* replacementLayer = instanceof Layer
   file = instanceof File with a property 'data' (data is a buffer)
   fileBuffer = instanceof Buffer */
```

I tried various ways of opening an image file and replacing the replacementLayer in the PSD but I can't get it to work. Simply overwriting the property with a new Buffer object is not enough.

Saving the image as a PNG is as simple as

```
psd.image.saveAsPng('./output.png')
```

Ideally, the image that is used to replace the replacementLayer should 'fill' to the width and height of the layer.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have the algorithm for skewing the image ? because simple "replacing" layers will not do the job in this instance

Comment: Did you ever figure this out in Node?

Comment: @HMilbradt no, I did not.

Comment: @JochemStoel have you, by any chance, resolved the issue? I am looking for something similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ag-psd can handle this, but the saved PSD does not render the outermost layer

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).